Regex match only when there is no printable characters anywhere behind it
As an example, I want to match the letter A, if there are 0 or more is white spaces behind it and no printable character, I want a solution that will broudly work in the default python java, golang, and other engines.
Match this:
     A   

Not this:
  x  A  

I can do this in PHP with the syntax below, but \K is not supported in many engines (default python, java, golang)
^\s*\KA(?=\s*$)

I can do this:
^(?:\s*)A

but it will match on all the spaces before the A as well, which is not what I want.
I feel like the solution should be pretty obvious, but I'm blanking. I know in a lookahead I can easily do this, for example, if I wanted to match 'A' and not any printable characters after, then I would simply do:
A(?=\s*$)

to match the 'A' here:
A     

and not here:
A    x 

But I'm not sure how to do this for a lookbehind because in most engines a * quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width, which is an error. I understand that in javascript this is valid syntax

Why not ^(?:\s*)(A) and get the contents of the first capture group?

@MT0 Yes, that will work. is there a way to do it without the non capture group?

With "behind it", do you mean before it?

What does \K mean, and how does ^\s*\KC(?=\s*$) match A without ever mentioning it?

@nocomment & @Goku : It should be ^\s*\KA(?=\s*$) (with A instead of C) and \K is used to reset the starting point of the match, meaning that all the characters consumed by ^\s* are not consumed by the full match. So no, the only thing I would propose is to do what @MTO proposes, by just accessing the matching group around the "A". I would potentially capture the spaces before and after in other groups, because Golang won't accept your variable-length lookahead (example: https://regex101.com/r/CFgMYN/1)


is it okay to just capture A? then something liken ^(?=[ ]*(A)[ ]*$) would work. 2) is a two step attempt feasable (first validate the pattern and then match A on the strings that qualify? 3)you could use variable length lookbehinds like (?<=^[ ]{0,99})A(?=[ ]*$) in Java and Javascript. You could use - as you mentioned - ^[ ]*\KA(?=[ ]*$) would work in Python, using the regex package. Do not know if it is possible in golang...


Use:
^(?:\s*)(A)(?=\s*$)

or, more simply:
^\s*(A)\s*$

and, with either option, get the contents of the first capture group.
